# I have two selects and I want the result table to be a union of the two

Tags: mysql, database

My goal is to access my DB and get two things:

1st - How many Computers are there in each classroom:

```
select 
    room.idRoom, count(*) as 'Existing Computers'
from
    room,
    computer
where
    room.idRoom = computer.idRoom
group by room.idRoom
```

2nd - How many computers are being used:

```
select 
    room.idRoom,
    count(*) as 'Computers Used'
from
    room,
    session,
    computer
where
    room.idRoom = computer.idRoom
        and computer.idComputer = session.idComputer
        and session.logout is null
group by room.idRoom
```

Although this two queries work fine separatly, I wanted my result table to show only the rooms which have the number of `'Existing Computers'` equal to the number of `'Computers Used'` . The main objective is to have a list of the rooms completly full. Preferably in this fashion:

```
idRoom | Existing Computers | Computers Used 
B100   |      4             |        4
B101   |      10            |        10
```

I'm sorry for not using the right format for this question, but I'm new to stackoverflow and I have little time to figure this out because my project is due this sunday.
Thank you for your help in advance :)

Comment: can you share the structure of both your tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Select ext.idRoom,
    ExistingComputers as 'Existing Computers',
    ComputersUsed as 'Computers Used'
from
    (select 
        room.idRoom, count(*) as ExistingComputers
    from
        room,
        computer
    where
        room.idRoom = computer.idRoom
    group by room.idRoom) as ext
inner join
    (select 
        room.idRoom,
        count(*) as ComputersUsed
    from
        room,
        session,
        computer
    where
        room.idRoom = computer.idRoom
            and computer.idComputer = session.idComputer
            and session.logout is null
    group by room.idRoom) as usd
on ext.idRoom = usd.idRoom
and ext.ExistingComputers = usd.ComputersUsed
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

So join them:

```
Select t1.idRoom, t1.ExistingComputers, t2.UsedComputers
    (select 
        room.idRoom, count(*) as ExistingComputers
    from  
        room,
        computer  
    where
        room.idRoom = computer.idRoom
    group by room.idRoom) t1
inner join 
    (select 
        room.idRoom,
        count(*) as UsedComputers
    from
        room,
        session,
        computer
    where
        room.idRoom = computer.idRoom
            and computer.idComputer = session.idComputer
            and session.logout is null
    group by room.idRoom) t2 on t1.idRoom = t2.idRoom
```

I've kept your pseudo-code as is. The basic idea is that you give an alias to the first table you're selecting and an alias to the second table you're selecting and then join them on idRoom.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one query, without subqueries.

If you join computers to sessions where logout is NULL, then you'll get only

```
SELECT r.idRoom, COUNT(*) AS 'Existing Computers In Use'
FROM room AS r
JOIN computer AS c ON r.idRoom=c.idRoom
JOIN session AS s ON c.idComputer=s.idComputer 
WHERE s.logout IS NULL
GROUP BY r.idRoom
```

It's worthwhile to use the SQL-92 `JOIN` syntax.